# How to get part of html markup as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I need to extract part of html markup:

```
<div id='path'>
  <span class='spant' data-id=0>HOME</span>
  <span class='spant' data-id=5>HOME</span>
  <span class='spant' data-id=9>HOME</span>
  <span class='spant' data-id=14>HOME</span>
  <span class='spant' data-id=11>HOME</span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.spant', function () {
  var a = ... // - html of all spant before clicked, including clicked one;
});
```

For example, if third `spant` is clicked, the result should be:

```
<span class='spant' data-id=0>HOME</span>
<span class='spant' data-id=5>HOME</span>
<span class='spant' data-id=9>HOME</span>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Use the `lt` selector.  https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki, this is not duplicate, man...

Comment: @Zakaria, you are wrong. This question has nothing common with the question you linked.

Comment: @bonaca, here is solution, quick and fast: https://jsfiddle.net/cj3L999o/ probably there are more elegant solutions, but this works, for sure. ;) Native JS helps, in cases like this... :)

Comment: @sinisake, it works. You should place your comment as answer.

Comment: @bonaca, nevermind, i couldn't, because question was closed, and now you already have (slightly better) answer from james bond. ;)

Comment: @sinisake, thanks a lot. Btw I suppose Zakaria closed this post, but it's not duplicated with the linked one. What can I do in this situation, when a moderator is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) jquery method - and to include the *clicked one* use `add(this)` too.

See a demo below where you get the list of the *markup* when you click on the `spant` using a `map()` function:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.spant', function() {
  var a = $(this).prevAll().add(this).map(function() {
    return $(this).get();
  }).get();
  console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='path'>
  <span class='spant' data-id=0>HOME</span>
  <span class='spant' data-id=5>HOME</span>
  <span class='spant' data-id=9>HOME</span>
  <span class='spant' data-id=14>HOME</span>
  <span class='spant' data-id=11>HOME</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should provide you a solution

```
$('.spant').on('click', function(e) {
    var string = "";
    var spans = $(this).prevAll().each(function(i, v){ string +=  v.outerHTML + "\n"; });
    string += this.outerHTML;
    alert(string);
});
```

Working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/xq44f1xa/

Answer (score 2):

Because you are already using jquery, I'd suggest `.prevAll()`

I'm not testing this, but it might look somethinglike:

```
$(document).on('click', '.spant', function () {
var a = $(this).prevAll().html() + $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: @TecBrat, this will not work, test it... OP needs outerHTML, actually...

Comment: @Landaida, please write your comment as answer, but clearly and tested before.

Comment: @Landaida, it works. You should place your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2):

this work fine [source](http://codepen.io/landaida/pen/wgGRGe), open developer mode in your browser to show console.log results

```
$(document).on('click', '.spant', function(){
    let befores = $(this).prevAll()
    ,all = befores.add(this)
    let html = '';
    $(all).each((index, item)=>{ html += item.outerHTML +'\n' })
    console.log(html)
})
```